# PIVOT Multiple Columns with different calculations

Tags: sql, pivot

I know this question has been asked but I've yet to find an answer that fits my issue

I have this structure

[image: Table structure]

I need to pivot on record count, approved, Signed per day so that it looks like this:

[image: Pivoted]

Please let me know if you need me to provide anything else
I appreciate any guidance.  thank you

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Date functions are quite database-specific.  The following gives the idea and should work in most databases:

```
select month(date) as mon, year(date) as yr, which,
       sum(case when day(date) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as day_01,
       sum(case when day(date) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as day_02,
       . . .
       sum(case when day(date) = 31 then 1 else 0 end) as day_31
from ((select date, 'reccount' as which, 1 as val from t
      ) union all
      (select date, 'approved' as which, approved as val from t
      ) union all
      (select date, 'signed' as which, signed as val from t
      ) 
     ) t
group by month(date), year(date), which
order by min(date), which ;
```